# Convert unirest to curl

Tags: php, curl, unirest

I want to use jsonWhois api but it makes the server request using Unirest, which looks like it's no longer maintained and I would prefer to use curl anyway.

How can I convert this code to use Curl instead??

```
$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://jsonwhois.com/api/v1/whois", 

   array(
    "Accept" => "application/json",
    "Authorization" => "Token token=<Api Key>"
   ),

   array(
       "domain" => "google.com"
   )

);

$data = $response->body; // Parsed body
```

I've tried `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://jsonwhois.com/api/v1/whois?token=123456&domain=google.com');`, but it says `HTTP Token: access denied`.

Comment: Looking at the original code, it seems like the token needs to be sent in the header and not as a query param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use Postman app for something like this. I use it all the time and it works great.

You can simply enter the request into it:

[image: request parameters]

And then simply click on "Code" (top right corner) and go to "PHP" -> "cURL". It will show you the exact code that you have to write to make that request using cURL:

[image: PHP cURL code]

I have no idea what jsonwhois is but, if everything is set up correctly, it should work.